# Why does one model overfits faster than another?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting, validation

Lets' say we have 2 models and we train both of them on the same data for the same number of epochs. When we monitor the validation loss, we realize that the point where the validation loss stops decreasing and starts increasing for model 1 shows up at epoch 5 while this point shows up at epoch 25 for model 2. What could be a possible explanation?

Here's a picture of the graphs to better understand what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Do the models have similar numbers of parameters to train?

Comment: No, I expected that models with more parameters with a high number of parameters overfit in a slower manner but that's not the case, for example, deepar has  240.7k parameters, while mlp has 174.8k, lstm 309.9k and nbeats 3822.9k